# SGE script to use one task per core for an MPI job

Tags: amazon-web-services, mpi

I have an AWS cluster created using cnfcluster. It is composed of 4 m4.xlarge nodes. I am trying to write an sge script that uses one task per core. Irrespective of any changes, I am only seeing one host in the output.
Could anyone suggest changes to the script?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-121:~$ qconf -sh 
ip-172-31-16-28.us-west-2.compute.internal
ip-172-31-20-128.us-west-2.compute.internal 
ip-172-31-29-121.us-west-2.compute.internal 
ip-172-31-30-78.us-west-2.compute.internal 
ip-172-31-30-81.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

SGE script

```
#!/bin/bash 
# 
#$ -cwd 
#$ -j y 
#$ -pe mpi 8 
#$ -S /bin/bash 
mpirun -np 8 hostname
```

Output

```
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78 
ip-172-31-30-78
```

Comment: MPI process pinning is usually implementation specific. Which MPI implementation are you using (MPICH, Open MPI, Intel MPI, etc.)?

Comment: @WesleyBland See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Installing OpenMPI (2.1.1) with SGE option fixed my problem with using multiple nodes.

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-sge
```

Changes in cluster configuration (check AWS cfncluster) helped with setting one task per core.